# Kafka ConsumerGroup is stable but no consumption when message in topic when using TestContainer with embeddedZookeeper

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, testcontainers

we have integration tests on **springboot** written using **TestContainers**.
Application has dependency on kafka and has **various producers and consumers** to implement event driven processing, therefore using container with following environment:

```
@ClassRule    
public static final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer= new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest"))
    .withEnv("KAFKA_MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS", "600000")
    .withEnv("KAFKA_SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS","660000")
    .withEnv("KAFKA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS", "120000")
    .withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_OFFSET_RESET", "earliest")
    .withEnv("KAFKA_MAX_POLL_RECORDS", "1")
    .withEnv("KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR", "1")
    .withEnv("KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_NUM_PARTITIONS", "1");
```

Please note that each consumer implementation takes less than a minute to consume message if listener receives the record.
Checking if any active consumers in group:

```
docker exec -it c3a824644d40 kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --describe --group my-test-group
```

Checking if any messages in topic :

```
docker exec -it c3a824644d40 /bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic testTopic --from-beginning
H10283e4c-a1f3-4d78-9926-91d4404bf2f1H9bd9905f-0e7a-4f22-b1eb-892f615f67e6~<someMessage>
```

So there is a message in the topic, which was produced by a previous producer:

```
2021-12-11 12:46:20.723  INFO 20229 --- [ntainer#2-0-C-1] c.n.e.n.s.k.p.TestTopicProducer  : {"level":"INFO","log":{"classname":"xxxxx","message":"request: xxxxx Sent SuccessFully on Partition: 0","threadcontext":{},"threadname":"org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#2-0-C-1"},"time":"2021-12-11T07:16:20.722Z","timezone":"xxxx","type":"log"}
```

but no consumer listener is receiving this message:

```
$ docker exec -it c3a824644d40 kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  --describe --group my-test-group
$
```

My Listener impl:

```
public class TestServiceConsumer implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<String, TestPojoRequest> {
@Autowired
private TestService testService;

@Override
@KafkaListener(
        topicPattern = "testTopic",
        containerFactory = "testGroupListenerContainerFactory",
        groupId = "my-test-group")
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, TestPojoRequest> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
    log.info("request: {}. listening To TestPojoRequest Thread ID: {}",
            record.value().getRequestOperationId(),
            Thread.currentThread().getId());
    try {
        testService.consumerMyMessage(record.value());
    } catch (JDBCConnectionException e) {
        log.error("request: {} Thread ID: {} for TestPojoRequest has an Unhandled error:",
                record.value().getRequestOperationId(),
                Thread.currentThread().getId(), e);
        throw new RecoverableDataAccessException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
  }
}
```

It takes about 4 minutes for the consumer to become active and consume the message after which when checking console:

```
2021-12-11 12:50:42.655  INFO 20229 --- [ntainer#3-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : my-test-group: partitions revoked: []
    2021-12-11 12:50:42.698  INFO 20229 --- [ntainer#3-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : my-test-group: partitions assigned: [testTopic-0]
    2021-12-11 12:50:42.706 DEBUG 20229 --- [ntainer#3-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Received: 1 records
    2021-12-11 12:50:42.708 DEBUG 20229 --- [ntainer#3-0-C-1] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
    2021-12-11 12:50:42.709 DEBUG 20229 --- [ntainer#3-0-C-1] .a.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaNull@77d67a19, headers={id=087068d5-dc08-ab1b-cc33-7b92cdb82d16, timestamp=1639206940507}]]


    GROUP           CONSUMER-ID                                                      HOST            CLIENT-ID                  #PARTITIONS     ASSIGNMENT
my-test-group   consumer-my-test-group-6-ecf3ba58-4577-4b7c-9037-f5cdb7c00717    /172.17.0.1     consumer-my-test-group-6   0               -


GROUP             COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY  STATE           #MEMBERS
my-test-group     457cd1f2680e:9092 (1)     range                Stable          1

GROUP                 TOPIC      PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG  CONSUMER-ID  HOST  CLIENT-ID
my-test-group         testTopic  0          -               -               -    -            -     -
```

Running single broker , embedded zookeeper , with single partitions and concurrency set to 1.

My producer config:

```
    @Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServiceHostWithPort);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryHostWithPort);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 5);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG, 4194304);
    return props;
}
```

My consumer config:

```
    public Map<String, Object> setCommonConsumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServiceHostWithPort);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 5000);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
    propsMap.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY, TopicRecordNameStrategy.class.getName());
    propsMap.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryHostWithPort);
    propsMap.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, (1000 * 60 * 60 * getIntegerValue(maxPollingDurationHours)));
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, "read_uncommitted");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, EARLIEST);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    return propsMap;
}

    @Bean
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, TestPojoRequest>> testGroupListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TestPojoRequest> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    Map<String, Object> propsMap = setCommonConsumerConfigs();
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-test-group");
    factory.setConsumerFactory(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(propsMap));
    factory.setConcurrency(1);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
    factory.setErrorHandler(((thrownException, consumerRecord) -> log.error("request: {} - Exception occurred when processing TestPojoRequest event {} ", ((TestPojoRequest) Objects.requireNonNull(consumerRecord).value()).getRequestOperationId(), consumerRecord, thrownException)));
    final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> exceptionsMap = new HashMap<>();
    exceptionsMap.put(RecoverableDataAccessException.class, true);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(getRetryTemplate(exceptionsMap));
    addFailureCallback(factory);
    return factory;
}
```

Additionally have set the config in all consumers:

```
       factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
```

And among many of my consumer groups for different topics, this listener is the only one where I see 4 minutes delay in consuming message. I can see some rebalancing happen in zookeper logs for this group even though we have set polltimeout , heartbeat interval and session timeouts to very high values.

The test case creates 1 message per topic and I have 1 consumer group per topic.
Ideally if messages are consumed correctly overall test case which has 6 messages in 6 different topics consumed sequentially by different groups would take only about 4-5 minutes, but because of delay(4 minutes delay) in message consumption the test runs for 9 minutes.
Need some help to figure out why rebalance of partitions and why message not consumed instantly and only after 4 minutes delay.

Comment: You'll need to show your consumer code. You've disabled auto commit, so `kafka-consumer-groups` won't show any offsets. Also, maybe related, but `KAFKA_OFFSETS.TOPIC*` are not a valid env variable (needs all underscores). Max poll records and auto offset reset aren't broker configs, therefore aren't broker env vars, either

Comment: The logs you've shown happen all within the same minute, by the way

Comment: @OneCricketeer
I have logged the producer and consumer logs of when message produced (2021-12-11 12:46:20.723) and when the listener is able to  receive it(2021-12-11 12:50:42.655) this is always consistently 4 minutes. Infact I am running the whole setup in debug mode as well but still not able to figure out why the rebalances are happening, since max poll records, max session, max poll ms , hearbeat interval ms have been set to avoid them.

Comment: @OneCricketeer i can update with consumer code as well it manual acknowledge,  and regarding the configs, looks like it was a typo will correct them

Comment: I'm overall not sure about the time duration, but since looks like you're passing through the record to some external JDBC service, have you tried using the Kafka Connect JDBC sink instead?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? It's taking me consistently 30s for consumer against testcontainer to receive and log message.